# Expression has changed after it was checked error

Tags: html, angular, typescript, wep

I make code that popup tooltip if there are overflow in the element and dont show tooltip if there are no overflow

```
<div class="title">
<div #titleElement class="ttt" [innerHtml]="title" data-toggle="tooltip" 
data- placement="bottom" [title]=isOverflown(titleElement)?title:null></div>
</div>
```

type script code :

```
isOverflown(titleElement) {
return titleElement.scrollHeight > titleElement.clientHeight || 
titleElement.scrollWidth > titleElement.clientWidth ;
}
```

but just if the element has overflow it's case console error : **Expression has changed after it was checked**
[image]

Comment: This [Blog](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) includes explanation and solution

Comment: it's not useful